# How to keep UINavigationController's UINavigationBar transparent when modally presenting a controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a fullscreen view inside of a UINavigationController. When I attempt to present a modal view on top of it, the UINavigationBar changes to opaque, pushing down the content, before the modal view animates. How do I keep this from happening?

```
ContextMenuViewController *cmvc = 
    [[ContextMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[cmvc setDelegate:self];
UINavigationController *navControl = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cmvc];
[cmvc release];
[navControl.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navControl animated:YES];
[navControl release];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
    setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent 
             animated:NO];
```

The UINavigationController's root view does not have any transparency (status bar nor UINavigationBar), only the pushed controllers have the transparency.

I created a video of the issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSFvzTR5Ejk

Example source at: http://cl.ly/7lu2

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a very small test project and didn't see the issue you describe. I suggest you do the same thing. Start with the Navigation-based Application template. In the main nib, check the navigation controller's Wants Full Screen and Resize View From Nib, and make its nav bar transparent. In the root view controller's nib, put a button that you can respond to, set up the action, and paste in your code. Create the ContextMenuViewController class; there is no need to give it a nib.

Run the app and press the button. The modal view slides into place, with a transparent nav bar, without affecting the transparency of the nav bar that already exists and without moving the existing content.

So now, once you've proved to yourself that it works in this simple project, it's just a question of locating what you're doing different from that in the real project.

Comment: The root view of the UINavigationController does not have a transparent status bar nor a transparent UINavigationBar, this is probably why they are both reverting to opaque. I was able to reproduce the same issue with a new project.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question so that your issue can be reproduced by others. Describe better the nature of the initial view and the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the bar styles during viewDidLoad for the root View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO )

> OptionsViewController *detailViewController = [[OptionsViewController
>   alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
>
> UINavigationController *optionsController = [[UINavigationController
>   alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
>
> [detailViewController release];
>
> optionsController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
>   optionsController.navigationBar.opaque = YES;
>   optionsController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
>   optionsController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor
>   clearColor];
>
> optionsController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
>   [self presentModalViewController:optionsController animated:YES];
>
> [optionsController release];